# Origin and authenticity of this hadith?

Tags: source-identification, authenticity, deeds

> “Feed the hungry and visit a sick person, and free the slave, if he
>   be unjustly confined. Assist any person oppressed, whether Muslim or
>   non-Muslim.”
>
> ― Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)

There are two hadiths like this in Sahih Al Bukhari.

1. Sahih al-Bukhari 3046 Book 56, Hadith 252
2. Sahih al-Bukhari 5649 Book 75, Hadith 9

However I say like, due to both of these hadiths in Sahih Al Bukhari fail to mention the part of, "Assist any person oppressed, whether Muslim or non-Muslim."

So were does this hadith originate (with the addition of the non-Muslim part). Also what is the authenticity of the hadith in question?

Link to where I found this saying attributed to Prophet Muhammad (PBUH):

https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/300788-feed-the-hungry-and-visit-a-sick-person-and-free

Comment: It seems the link you quoted has been removed

Comment: It's first part appears in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/70/1). [this article](https://jes.pennpress.org/media/73792/montville_article_jes_512.pdf) quotes it as a saying of the prophet which they refer to a link on [this site](http://www.twf.org/Sayings/Sayings2.html#Contentment) but they don't give references for these sayings of the prophet (). I think the quoted statement is a mix of many sources (ahadith?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Assist any person oppressed, **whether Muslim or non-Muslim**."

The bold part seems to have been added on and it has no origin in any of the *Sahih ahadith*

It's possible that someone has mixed up the narrations, however I couldn't find any that ended with "Muslim or non-Muslim."

I doubt it's a saying of the Prophet since he never used the term "non-Muslim"

Allaho Alim

Answer (score 1):

Asalaam alaikum.

I would point to Sahih Bukhari 2445 Book 46, Hadith 6 (talking about 7 things Prophet Muhammad, pbuh, orders us to do, including helping the oppressed). And I would also point to other related hadiths like the one at Sunnan Abu Dawud, Volume No. 3, Page No. 170, Hadith No. 3052 (about how Prophet Muhammad himself will testify on Judgment Day against anyone who oppresses a non-Muslim living in Muslim lands). 
Here's a link to several narrations by Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) about oppression: http://sunnah.com/bukhari/46

And here is a page with more narrations of Prophet Muhammad's mercy to non-Muslims: http://the-finalrevelation.blogspot.com/2012/09/Mercy-ofthe-prophet-for-Nonmuslims.html

Hope this is all helpful!  Any good is from Allah swt and any mistakes or shortcomings are my own, and may Allah swt forgive me.  Wa'salaam.

Answer (score -2):

"Beware! Whoever is cruel and hard on a non-Muslim minority, curtails their rights, burdens them with more than they can bear, or takes anything from them against their free will; I (Prophet Muhammad) will complain against the person on the Day of Judgment." (Abu Dawud)